# PHP Script That Creates File Suddenly Stops Working

Tags: php, echo, fopen, fwrite

I made a script to create a file, it was working fine until i think my host changed the script when I asked them what was wrong with it (I fixed it after but now its not working)

Here is the script:

```php
$rand = substr(md5(microtime()),rand(0,26),5);
        $seed = str_split('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
                 .'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
                 .'0123456789!@#$%^&*()' . 'ǀǁǂǃǄǅǆǇǈǉǊǋǌǍǎǏ01D0ǐǑǒǓǔǕǖǗǘǙǚǛǜǝǞǟ01E0ǠǡǢǣǤǥǦǧǨǩǪǫǬǭǮǯ01F0ǰǱǲǳǴǵǶǷǸǹǺǻǼǽǾǿ
0200ȀȁȂȃȄȅȆȇȈȉȊȋȌȍȎȏ0210ȐȑȒȓȔȕȖȗȘșȚțȜȝȞȟ0220ȠȡȢȣȤȥȦȧȨȩȪȫȬȭȮȯ0230ȰȱȲȳȴȵȶȷȸȹȺȻȼȽȾȿ0240ɀɁɂɃɄɅɆɇɈɉɊɋɌɍɎɏ0250ɐɑɒɓɔɕɖɗɘəɚɛɜɝɞɟ0260ɠɡɢɣɤɥɦɧɨɩɪɫɬɭɮɯ0270ɰɱɲɳɴɵɶɷɸɹɺɻɼɽɾɿ0280ʀʁʂʃʄʅʆʇʈʉʊʋʌʍʎʏ0290ʐʑʒʓʔʕʖʗʘʙʚʛʜʝʞʟ02A0ʠʡʢʣʤʥʦʧʨʩʪʫʬʭʮʯ02B0ʰʱʲʳʴʵʶʷʸʹʺʻʼʽʾʿ02C0ˀˁ˂˃˄˅ˆˇˈˉˊˋˌˍˎˏ02D0ːˑ˒˓˔˕˖˗˘˙˚˛˜˝˞˟02E0ˠˡˢˣˤ˥˦˧˨˩˪˫ˬ˭ˮ˯02F0˰˱˲˳˴˵˶˷˸˹˺˻˼˽˾˿0300̀́̂̃̄̅̆̇̈̉̊̋̌̍̎̏0310̛̖̗̘̙̜̝̞̟̐̑̒̓̔̕̚0320̡̢̧̨̠̣̤̥̦̩̪̫̬̭̮̯0330̴̵̶̷̸̰̱̲̳̹̺̻̼̽̾̿0340͇͈͉͍͎̀́͂̓̈́͆͊͋͌ͅ͏0350͓͔͕͖͙͚͐͑͒͗͛͘͜͟͝͞0360ͣͤͥͦͧͨͩͪͫͬͭͮͯ͢͠͡0370ͰͱͲͳʹ͵Ͷͷ͸͹ͺͻͼͽ;Ϳ0380΀΁΂΃΄΅Ά·ΈΉΊ΋Ό΍ΎΏ0390ΐΑΒΓΔΕΖΗΘΙΚΛΜΝΞΟ03A0ΠΡ΢ΣΤΥΦΧΨΩΪΫάέήί03B0ΰαβγδεζηθικλμνξο03C0πρςστυφχψωϊϋόύώϏ03D0ϐϑϒϓϔϕϖϗϘϙϚϛϜϝϞϟ03E0ϠϡϢϣϤϥϦϧϨϩϪϫϬϭϮϯ03F0ϰϱϲϳϴϵ϶ϷϸϹϺϻϼϽϾϿ
'); // and any other characters
shuffle($seed); // probably optional since array_is randomized; this may be redundant
$rand = '';
foreach (array_rand($seed, 50) as $k) $rand .= $seed[$k];
$current = "";

fputs($rand, "[Server]: Welcome To Your New Chat Server");
echo $rand;
```

Its meant to create a random file and show the user the name of that file

I always get an error:

> ec-2017 08:52:43 UTC] PHP Warning:  fputs() expects parameter 1 to be
>   resource, string given in /public_html/rechat/nokeep.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fputs` is expecting a resource ( as the error points out) this should be the handle from `fopen()`...

```
$fh = fopen($rand, 'w');
fputs($fh, "[Server]: Welcome To Your New Chat Server");
fclose($fh);
```

You could alternatively use `file_put_contents()` which would do this all in one step...

```
file_put_contents($rand,  "[Server]: Welcome To Your New Chat Server");
```